# How do I query a list of posts of a custom post type and one category?

Tags: php, wordpress

This query should include all posts of a custom post type that have a category called "featured" or the ID of 20. I'm trying to get this to work on a static frontpage, rather than on a category or archive template.

I am able to get the custom post type, but not the category.

```
global $post;
$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'offset'=> 1,
    'post_type' => 'project', // name of custom post type.
    //'category' => 20, // if adding ID of category, no posts are returned.
); 

$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $lastposts as $post ) :
    setup_postdata( $post ); 
    echo the_title();
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

UPDATE: as requested, here is the register_post_type() for the custom post type, "project".

```
$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'can_export'         => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'  => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'rewrite'            => apply_filters( 'et_project_posttype_rewrite_args', array(
        'feeds'      => true,
        'slug'       => 'project',
        'with_front' => false,
    ) ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'author', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields' ),
);

register_post_type( 'project', apply_filters( 'et_project_posttype_args', $args ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( 20 )
        ),
    ),
);
$query_post = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $query_post->have_posts() ) {
....
}
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: this seems like it would work... but isn't returning anything. the if statement: `$query_post -> have_posts()` returns false.

Comment: Show your register post type

Comment: I updated the question with the register_post_type() function for custom post type, "project"

Comment: You should add 'taxonomies' => array( "category") to $args.

Comment: that is not working... is there anything else I can try?